# Sort an Map with Maps inside

Tags: javascript, sorting

is there a way to sort a Map of Maps in JS?

```
function travelTime(array) {
    let countryOrdersMap = new Map()

    for (let commands of array) {
        let [country, townName, cost] = commands.split(" > ");
        cost = Number(cost);

        if (!countryOrdersMap.has(country)) {
            countryOrdersMap.set(country, new Map());
            countryOrdersMap.get(country).set(townName, cost)

        } else {
            let countryTown = countryOrdersMap.get(country)
            for (let test of countryTown) {
                let name = test.shift()
                let newCost = test.shift()
                if (name !== townName) {
                    countryOrdersMap.get(country).set(townName, cost)
                } else {
                    let finalCost = Math.min(cost, newCost)
                    countryOrdersMap.get(country).set(townName, finalCost)
                }
            }
        }

    }
travelTime([
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 1000",
    "Bulgaria > Sopot > 800",
    "France > Paris > 2000",
    "Albania > Tirana > 1000",
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 1200"
])
```

I have to sort these by two criteria:

1. by key alphabetically (Albania, Bulgaria , France )
2. by values of the second map in descending order ( Sopot - 800, Sofia - 100)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

I've tried several different tactics with no success.

Comment: Have you considered ordering the values in an array *before* adding them to the `Map` object?

Comment: Aren't maps meant to be unordered?

Comment: How do you get to `Sofia - 100`?

Comment: @Konrad Not JS `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the data and sort parts.

```js
const
    data = ["Bulgaria > Sofia > 1000", "Bulgaria > Sopot > 800", "France > Paris > 2000", "Albania > Tirana > 1000", "Bulgaria > Sofia > 1200"];

data.sort((a, b) => {
    const
        aa = a.split(' > '),
        bb = b.split(' > ');

    let r = 0;
    [0, 1].some(i => r = aa[i].localeCompare(bb[i]));
    return r || bb[2] - aa[2];
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const
    array = ["Bulgaria > Sofia > 1000", "Bulgaria > Sopot > 800", "France > Paris > 2000", "Albania > Tirana > 1000", "Bulgaria > Sofia > 1200"];

    array.sort((a, b) => {
    let newARr = []
    const
        aa = a.split(' > '),
        bb = b.split(' > ');
    newARr.push(aa)
    newARr.push(bb)
    let finalSort = []

    newARr.sort(([country, city, price], [country2, city2, price2]) => {
        finalSort = country2.localeCompare(country) || city2.localeCompare(city) || price2 - price;
    })
    return finalSort
})
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this sorting is also sufficient ? Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).